# Get row id, if user exist in a column array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 3 column

```
id   user   food

1    Sam    Apple, Banana, Orange

2    Beni    Apple, Jam, Orange

3    Nancy    Apple, Banana, Orange
```

Here in the "food" column, Banana is exist in the row 1 and 3. How to get the row number when an item(Banana) in the food column is same.

Thank you !

Comment: do you want the ID or the row number ???

Comment: Isn't Banana in your user column?

Comment: @annampriyatam, ID number.

Comment: @almasshaikh, Nr brother, it is in food column.

Comment: so what exactly is your issue? And What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want the row Id's where Banana is there. I can only check is there any Banana in a specific row(given) but not in whole table.

Comment: Then you can use..

    SELECT id FROM tableName WHERE food='banana';

Comment: @annampriyatam, How? food has three values. How it can extract only Banana?

Comment: ohh sorry.. i didn't notice that... to get that we have to use a bit of PHP code..

Comment: first get those values from DB and "explode" them and then check for the value in the array using "in_array"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a very basic level, you can use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT id FROM DATABASE_NAME WHERE food LIKE "%Banana%";
```

But this won't stop a result such as "Apple, Banana cake, Orange" appearing instead. You should consider storing the food in a different table and create a JOIN instead.

TABLE user:

```
id   user
1    Sam
2    Beni
3    Nancy
```

TABLE userfood:

```
id      userid      food
1       1           Apple
2       1           Banana
3       1           Orange
4       2           Apple
5       2           Jam
6       2           Orange
7       3           Apple
8       3           Banana
9       3           Orange
```

Now we can create a much better query:

```
SELECT user.id
FROM user
JOIN userfood ON userfood.userid = user.id
WHERE food = 'Banana'
```

Now you'll have the user IDs and can easily (and *reliably*) search for whichever food that you want to.

Comment: Thank you Bro...its a big solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below query

```
SELECT id FROM DATABASE_NAME 
WHERE food="Banana";
```

Comment: Bro, 3 fruits are in all three row. Banana is exist in row (ID) 1 and 3. is it possible to query like this?